# How did lose my bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, fraud, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I met this guy online and he wanted to teach me trading. so he  said I needed to log in my wallet in my wallet which I did then he sent a link of team viewer (https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/).

The next thing my wallet was sending my bitcoin to an address.. I did not do this, how did it happen? Everything happened so fast.. Nobody knew my password or even my wallet key... How did my wallet send the initiate the transaction by itself?

Comment: "I needed to log in my wallet" With your help, you decrypted it.

Answer (score 1):

You gave a scammer access to your wallet, logging into it and then giving them access to the computer that was logged into the wallet. I'm sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 0):

By installing or running the "team viewer" program you gave the guy control over your computer using his keyboard and mouse.

After you entered the password to open your wallet, the wallet is unprotected and he could then use his keyboard and mouse to click buttons in your wallet to make a payment to  his address.

---

> I did not do this,

He did it

> how did it happen?

by installing or running team-viewer, you gave him control over your computer.

> Everything happened so fast.. Nobody knew my password or even my wallet key

He didn't need to know your password because he tricked you into entering your password when you opened your wallet.

> How did my wallet send the initiate the transaction by itself?

Your wallet didn't do this itself, the scammer used his keyboard and mouse in the same way you would. Probably he used tools to speed up the typing so that it happened too fast for you to see all the details.